# Facebook application - Development model

Tags: facebook

We are building couple of facebook application. Right now we have setup 3 different setup for each application. For example for app1 we will have 1) app1_dev for development 2) app1_test for testing and 3) app1 for live users.

All three apps point to different callback urls.

Our development team check-in code into SVN and build script put all these code on test server.

Once testing is done we move it to live server.

My questions is 
1. Are we right?
2. Is there any area of improvement?
3. We are not doing unit testing, how can we test UI?

Answer (score 0):

the cycle which you are following for developing facebook applications is perfectly fine.Only if you keep all applications URL into properties file then that will be easier for you to change that URL anytime when you want.And the answer of your third question is to test UI I think you are proving facebook connect button so that user can also login to your site using their facebook account so from that only you can test it.No need to write testcase for UI testing.